# google chrome add things in my html code

Tags: xhtml, google-chrome

I've got a strange problem with chrome.

My code works like a charm in safari, chrome (5.x.x), explorer and firefox. But with a recent chrome update (7.x or 8.x) it doesn't.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
    <div class="result">

 <div class="favoris">
  <a class="favorisClick"><img src="images/favoris.png"</a>
 </div>

 <div class="favorisContent resultDim">
  <h1 class="favTitle">0 FAVORIS</h1>
  <ul id="favResult">
      <!-- js insert things here -->
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="resultContent resultDim">
  <h1 class="nbrResult">0 TITRES</h1>
  <ul id="resultContent">
   <!-- js insert things here -->
  </ul>
  <div id="nav">
   <ul>

   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="infos">
  <a class="infosClick"><img src='images/infoUp.png' alt='show info' /></a>

  <div class="infosContent">
   <ul id="infosContent">
    <li>Sélectionez un morceau.</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li id="dl"></li>
    <li></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

With safari, ff, old chrome and ie, i see this code with the added content by the js.

With a new version of chrome here's what i get :

```
<div class="result">
  <div class="favoris">
    <a class="favorisClick">
      <img src="images/favoris.png" <="" a=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <a class="favorisClick">
    <div class="favorisContent resultDim" style="display: none; ">
      <h1 class="favTitle">0 FAVORIS</h1>
      <ul id="favResult">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="resultContent resultDim">
      <h1 class="nbrResult">16 TITRES</h1>
      <ul id="resultContent">
        ***RESULT CONTENT***
      </ul>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="infos">
    <a class="favorisClick"/>
    <a class="infosClick">
    <div class="infosContent" style="display: none; ">
      <ul id="infosContent">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I dunno why it add this $&@$X1& `<a class="favorisClick">` and `</a>` and the `<a class="favorisClick" />` it happens ONLY whith recent chrome version ... it make me turn completely mad !!

I don't even know how to search for this issue on google...

Please help me :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="favoris">
  <a class="favorisClick"><img src="images/favoris.png"</a>
 </div>
```

It looks like you're not closing your image tag...

Comment: Yep, always validate before mentioning browser bugs :)